# Why are my Spring Data repositories not found if moved into another package of a Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I created a new project in Eclipse from these helpful spring examples (Import Getting Started Content). It is called "gs-accessing-data-rest-complete"

Reference and full Code can be found: [spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-rest](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-rest/tree/master/complete/src/main/java/hello)

When leaving the example unchanged, except using **WAR** instead of **JAR** packaging, everything works well. When calling `$ curl http://localhost:8080/`, I'll get an exposure of usable resources.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/
{
  "_links" : {
    "people" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/name{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
"profile" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/alps"
    }
  }
```

But when moving the `PersonRepository` into another package, e.g. `myRepos` via Eclipse's Refactor-->Move command, a resource is not accessible anymore.

The response from curl is then:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/alps"
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I understood, Spring scans for Repositories automatically. Because the main class uses [`@SpringBootApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation) annotation, everything should be found by spring itself.

What am I missing? Do I have to add some special XML configuration file or add another Configuration Class somewhere? Or do I have to update application.properties in order to sth.?

Perhaps somebody has some useful experiences, she or he might share with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the base package to use when scanning for repositories by using this annotation on your config class: `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.base.repository.package")`

Comment: Exactly. Thank you. I had a problem understanding, what my config class was, because I had no class having a `@Configuration`. In my simple project, it is the same class containing the `@SpringBootApplication` Annotation, which is in fact the main class. Here I let Spring discover all repositories.